# Clear values inside of the MutableLiveData response collection

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, fragment, android-livedata

I have an app, which uses api calls, to get some data by `Retrofit` from the server. I've implemented `SwiperRefreshLayout` to allow user, to perform another call.

Currently, I'm struggling with clearing `MutableLiveData` collection, which stores response from the server. I'd like to clear that collection every time the `OnRefreshListener` will be triggered.

I've tried to "fill" the `MutableLiveData` with `null` (as it comes by default, right?) but since I've set the observable in `OnCreateView` to pass the data to the `Adapter`, after every refresh I got `NullPointerException` error.

How I may solve it? Should I do something like unobserving, and observing the `response` collection again, when `OnRefreshListener` is triggered? Here's some code:

**ViewModel**

```
var responseData = MutableLiveData<Model?>()



fun fetchData(baseCurrency: String, selectedCurrencies: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response =
            retrofitRepository.fetchHistoricalData(date, selectedCurrencies, baseCurrency)
        response.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Model> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<HistoricalRatesModel>,
                response: Response<HistoricalRatesModel>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    responseData.value = response.body()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<HistoricalRatesModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure ERROR\n${t.message}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHistoricalRatesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = mBinding.root

      
        mViewModel.responseData.observe(requireActivity(), androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            mAdapter = Adapter()
            mAdapter?.setData(it!!.rates)
            mBinding.hrv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
            mBinding.hrv.adapter = mAdapter
        })

        mBinding.refreshContainer.setOnRefreshListener {
            mBinding.refreshContainer.isRefreshing = false
        }
        return view
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling that potential *null* value in your observer - in fact you're telling the compiler that it will never be null!

```
mViewModel.responseData.observe(requireActivity(), androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
    ...
    mAdapter?.setData(it!!.rates)
})
```

How you handle it depends on what you want to do when that *null* value is pushed to observers. If you want to clear the data in the adapter, you could do:

```
mAdapter?.setData(it?.rates ?: emptyList<Rate>())
```

or you could make your Adapter's `setData()` function accept *null* (and decide internally how to handle that) and then you can just do:

```
mAdapter?.setData(it?.rates)
```

If any of that's confusing, make sure you're familiar with the [null safety features in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types), and how `thing?.stuff?.value` evaluates to null if *any* of those variables in the chain are null